# Starting a program on Windows start-up (VM)

Tags: windows, boot, windows-server-2003

This quesion is related to Virtual Machine concept. We login to system using mstsc and [username]/[password].

If I run a program on startup by placing it in:

`C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` in Windows 2003 Server, will the program run when the actual machine started? or does it run only when we log in to VM using that [username]? Does it require to be placed in Administrator user account to expect it run on startup?

Answer (score 1):

1) Windows 2003 Server is no longer supported. Upgrade.

2) The program in `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` will run only after login. Use local policy `gpedit.msc` - `Computer configuration` to add scripts or commands to be launched at startup. Or you can use a Windows scheduled task.

[See this question](https://serverfault.com/q/266338/229754).

Comment: WIndows scheduled task should do the job! I have already implemented it. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Is there any way to view the output produced by a program started in this way?

Comment: @SergeRogatch I would just redirect output of the command or script. See https://superuser.com/q/278115/285900